# How do I solve project creation error when trying to create a flutter application using android studio 4.2.2

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I get the error message  below as a dialog popup message when I try creating a new flutter application project using android studio 4.2.2

Could not find an option named "platforms".
Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h) for available flutter commands and options

[image: image of the error message on android studio]